# Go - redirect to specific url with payload

Tags: http, go

I'm trying to implement payment method on my application, and I need help.

To show the payment page, I need to perform `POST` request to their url with a payment payload. Normally they will response with a html response, and after that I need to render it to screen. However, what I got is an error saying that session is invalid.

My question: is it possible to redirect to another url with `POST` and a request payload?

```
POST http://payment.api.net/merchant/init?corpid=CN000001
<order>
    <corp>NN01</corp>
    <amount>20.0</amount>
    <currency>USD</currency>
    <ordernumber>10010111</ordernumber>
    <redirect>http://mycallback.api.net/store/payment/callback</redirect>
    <randomstring>NnwLRINzhOgvmvyunzZIrUtCgvmvy</randomstring>
    <hash>4792e72f5e1860b220420ad3f22f005c9d2fce83f3a138336869780153145700</hash>
</order>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this code..

```html
<html>
 <body>
 <form action="http://payment.api.net/merchant/init?corpid=CN000001" method="post" enctype='text/plain'>
  <input type="hidden" name="order" value='<order><corp>NN01</corp><amount>20.0</amount><currency>USD</currency><ordernumber>10010111</ordernumber><redirect>http://mycallback.api.net/store/payment/callback</redirect><randomstring>NnwLRINzhOgvmvyunzZIrUtCgvmvy</randomstring><hash>4792e72f5e1860b220420ad3f22f005c9d2fce83f3a138336869780153145700</hash></order>'>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

May it solve your problem..